# Why is my Firebase Web Authentication Not Working?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to connect my website to the Firebase Database and authenticate users through Firebase Authentication. But I am struck at the very starting point. My website is hosted in Firebase, hence I am trying to initialise Firebase automatically. I have put test alerts to check if Firebase Authentication is working properly. The page is getting loaded and there is no issue with that:

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>****</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.20.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.20.-/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.20.-/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script> 
    <script>
       window.onload = function() {
               alert("Page Loaded");
            // Listening for auth state changes.
                firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                    alert("Firebase Connected");
                    if (user) {
                        // User is signed in.
                    } else {
                        // No user is signed in.
                    }
                });
             }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Page Loaded alert fires but Firebase Connected alert does not

Comment: i can't see the actual login code though. Are you by chance forgot to do the actual login?

Comment: Login Code is there. I can provide the same. But my problem is before the login. Firebase would check for the login status through the call of firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged, just after the page loads. This check is not being done.